# Rego Object matching and comparison

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I'm trying to match the domain key ("domain":"example.com") from the given input, and return an error if the values are not identical. This is what I've thought of so far, but I can't seem to match the domain key, thus the tests are failing. Any advice would be appreciated.

OPA Policy:

```
package main
import data.config

default warning_mode = []
warning_mode = config.warn_mode { config.warn_mode }

array_contains(arr, elem) {
  arr[_] = elem
}

exception[rules] {
    rules := config.exceptions.rules
}

deny_missing_config[msg] {
    not config
    msg := "Missing configuration file"
}

## Main

aws_ses_dkim[a] {
  a := input.resource_changes[_]
  a.type == "aws_ses_domain_dkim"
}

aws_ses_domain[e] {
  e := input.resource_changes[_]
  e.type == "aws_ses_domain_identity"
}

ses_missing_dkim[msg] {
    a := aws_ses_dkim[_]
    e := aws_ses_domain[_]
    walk(a, [["values", "domain"], x])
    walk(e, [["values", "domain"], y])
    err := x - y

    not err == set()
    msg := sprintf("Placeholder error", [err, a.address, e.address])
}


## Test Cases

deny_ses_missing_dkim[msg]{
  not array_contains(warning_mode, "ses_missing_dkim")
  ses_missing_dkim[_] != []
  msg := ses_missing_dkim[_]
}

warn_ses_missing_dkim[msg]{
  array_contains(warning_mode, "ses_missing_dkim")
  ses_missing_dkim[_] != []
  msg := ses_missing_dkim[_]
}

test_ses_missing_dkim_invalid {
    i := data.mock.invalid_ses_dkim
    r1 := warn_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as []
    count(r1) == 0
    r2 := warn_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as ["ses_missing_dkim"]
    count(r2) == 1
    r3 := deny_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as []
    count(r3) == 1
    r4 := deny_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as ["ses_missing_dkim"]
    count(r4) == 0
    count(r1) + count(r2) == 1
    count(r3) + count(r4) == 1
}

test_ses_missing_dkim_valid {
    i := data.mock.ses_dkim
    r1 := warn_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as []
    r2 := warn_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as ["ses_missing_dkim"]
    r3 := deny_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as []
    r4 := deny_ses_missing_dkim with input as i with data.config.warn_mode as ["ses_missing_dkim"]
    count(r1) + count(r2) + count(r3) + count(r4) == 0
}
```

Input (Terraform JSON):

```
                "resource_changes":[
                   {
                      "address":"aws_ses_domain_dkim.example",
                      "mode":"managed",
                      "type":"aws_ses_domain_dkim",
                      "name":"example",
                      "provider_name":"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws",
                      "schema_version":0,
                      "values":{
                         "domain":"example.com"
                      },
                      "sensitive_values":{
                         "dkim_tokens":[
                            
                         ]
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "address":"aws_ses_domain_identity.example",
                      "mode":"managed",
                      "type":"aws_ses_domain_identity",
                      "name":"example",
                      "provider_name":"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws",
                      "schema_version":0,
                      "values":{
                         "domain":"example.com"
                      },
                      "sensitive_values":{
                         
                      }
                   }
                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` and `y` values retrieved by the `walk` function will be strings, so `err := x - s` isn't going to work. If you want a set of values, you could wrap the `walk` call in a set comprehension to get a set of all values:

```
ses_missing_dkim[msg] {
    a := aws_ses_dkim[_]
    e := aws_ses_domain[_]
    xs := {x | walk(a, [["values", "domain"], x])}
    ys := {y | walk(e, [["values", "domain"], y])}
    
    err := xs - ys

    not err == set()
    
    msg := sprintf("Placeholder error", [err, a.address, e.address])
}
```

You probably don't need `walk` here though, as the values are always at a known path.

Comment: It didn't solve the main issue I am facing but this was indeed helpful non the less. Thank you.

Comment: I probably don't understand the main issue then :) Feel free to expand on that here, or the OPA Slack if that's more convenient.

Comment: What would be the alternative way to match "example.com" instead of using "walk"?

Comment: `a.values.domain` and `e.values.domain` respectively. if you want to aggregate them you could do `xs := {x | x := aws_ses_dkim[_].values.domain}